# How to generate a QR Code for each registered user?

Tags: javascript, html, database, qr-code

When a user register with my website i want to generate a QR code for each user. then user can access their profile via qr code easily.I know this is too difficult. so i need a online reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [qrcode.js](http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) to do that. Place a unique http url that points to the user profile as the qrcode data.

Usage example:

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "http://foo.bar/userProfileUrl");
</script>
```